# confusion implementing specflow bdd for resource-based api

Tags: bdd, specflow, gherkin

I'm trying to implement bdd into a project for the first time and have a couple of questions regarding language used with regards to the audiences.

I've seen lots of examples where the language is meant to be understood by end-users etc.  But what about if you're writing an api (rest style web-api with odata support) that's just going to be consumed by other developers?  Is it okay to be more specific or should you still try to keep it as simple as possible?

Secondly, do you have to specify values in the if you're describing it in a general sense e.g:

```
Scenario: product is defined for the first time

Given product code abcdefg does not already exist

When product definition with code abcdefg is uploaded

Then product is created

And user receives status 201 created with url 'blah'
```

but is it okay to abstract this into a more general case? e.g

```
Scenario: product is defined for the first time

Given product code does not already exist

When product definition is uploaded

then product is created

And user receives status 201 and creation url
```

thanks

**Update**

Thanks to sam and AlSki we've decided to split our specifications into 3 different types:

```
User: End-User facing, most declarative style concerning UI

Dev: More imperative and detailed, concerning data only interactions

System: Most imperative and detailed - concerning our internal stuff
```

Were now creating Scenario Outlines with multiple examples which seems to work well for testing all our edge cases.

I've also removed the outcomes that aren't observable by the external developer ("the product is created" etc) and think we all understand this better now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is Yes. You *can* do whatever you want to in BDD as long as it means something to the people who will be using it.

So, if you are a fully technical team and all happy using *status code 201* and *url* then go ahead.

Have a read up on the BDD advocates ([Dan North](http://blog.dannorth.net/), [Liz Keogh](http://lizkeogh.com/), [Gojko Adzic](http://gojko.net/), etc), and you will find that the important bit is to be talking to other people and using the same language in your specs that you use in your conversations, because you are encapsulating your knowledge and using that to test to.

However your second example is probably a step too far. Consider that BDD is also known as *Specification by example* and in this case you have removed the example. You've just got a general idea, but nothing concrete to test too.

Consider if that for some reason (and we've all seen one of these) that there is a special product code that does something different. How would you test for that?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've looked at Dan Norths stuff but whenever I tried to flesh out specifics I ended up writing a ton of scenarios for edge cases so I thought a more generic approach might help.

Comment: +1 for specific examples. I usually ask, "Can you give me an example?" to whoever the expert is, then try to use that language as much as I can in the scenarios. Also thanks for the plug! - Liz.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do is extract out steps which are generic but keep the specitivity in your test:

```
Scenario: product is defined for the first time
   Given product code 'abcdefg' does not already exist
   When product definition with code 'abcdefg' is uploaded
   Then product 'abcdefg' is created
   And user receives status 201 created with url 'blah'
```

which binds to steps like:

```
[Given("product code '(.*)' does not already exist")]
public void ProductCodeDoesNotExist(string productCode)
{...}
```

then you can reuse the same step to test for many products

Also I would suggest changing you step:

```
 And user receives status 201 created with url 'blah'
```

to something less implementation specific like:

```
 And the product is created successfully at the location 'blah'
```

As then they are less technical and you could reuse these steps to drive tests which test at your API layer and at you UI layer by simply replacing the step implementations that are used to bind to the steps.

In fact I would probably either merge your 2 `Then` steps or have this:

```
Then product 'abcdefg' is created successfully
And the created product is available at the location 'blah'
```

As I'm not sure what check you could be doing in

```
then product is created
```

which is not also implied in

```
And user receives status 201 and creation url
```